# Fastest way to determine if molecule has resonance structures

Tags: molecular-structure, resonance, lewis-structure

I came across this old exam problem:

> For which of the following choices, is **every** molecule a resonance hybrid with resonance structures?
>
> **A**. $\ce{SO2},$ $\ce{NH3},$ benzene
> **B**. $\ce{SO3^2-},$ $\ce{NH3},$ benzene
> **C**. $\ce{SO2},$ $\ce{NO3-},$ benzene
> **D**. $\ce{SO3^2-},$ $\ce{NO3-},$ benzene
> **E**. $\ce{SO3},$ ethanol, benzene

So, in order to solve this problem I don't actually have to draw any Lewis structure and what not, I just have to determine which molecules have resonance structures. But what is the fastest way to do that?

How can I determine if a molecule has resonance without having to draw anything, if that's even possible? I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: In the end, you do have to draw the molecules.

Comment: Incidentally, the answer is **C** although old textbooks might give it as **D** :D

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't have to do anything for benzene because it occurs in every choice.
2. You have to compare $\ce{SO2}$ and $\ce{SO3-}$ because they distinguish A) from B) and C) from D).
3. You have to compare $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ because the distinguish A) and B) from C) and D).
4. If you use this strategy, you miss out on the chance to figure out  $\ce{SO3}$, ethanol and benzene, and you would learn less.

Comment: Concerning 4: not really. For example, it could be that e.g. both $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ have none and it could be that more than one line is correct.

Comment: When you say "compare" do you indicate that I have to draw them? On a different note, are you danish? Your name seems danish.

Comment: @Jan Yes, I'm not saying it's a perfect strategy. In fact, I think it is a bad strategy for multiple reasons.

Comment: @Carl - I can visualize them in my head because I already drew them "a couple" of times. $\ce{NH3}$ has just one none-hydrogen atom, so any resonance would have to invoke something unusual. I don't understand the question - what does "one or more resonance structures" mean? How can you have resonance with a single structure?

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake copying the problem. I edited the question.